# iOS 14 - LNA permission not prompted when using custom cast dialog

Tags: swift, google-cast, ios14

We use the `GCKUICastButton` and set

```
triggersDefaultCastDialog = false
```

to show a custom receiver list. We do not set `disableDiscoveryAutostart` or `startDiscoveryAfterFirstTapOnCastButton`.

We would expect that when a user selects the cast button the first time they would get the local area network permissions prompt. However, we are never prompted. In order to get the prompt to show we have to call `startDiscovery()`.

Is this intended behavior? If not, are we missing something in our implementation?

Answer (score 2):

If you built a custom device picker in your app, then you will need to explicitly call the startDiscovery method on the GCKDiscoveryManager class to initiate device discovery. Automatic scanning has been disabled by default beginning with the v4.5.0 release of the Cast SDK.
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender/ios_permissions_changes#updating_your_app_on_ios_14

Comment: Per that doc: `By default, Cast device discovery is initiated the first time the user taps the Cast button (GCKUICastButton). If it's the first time the user has attempted to use the Cast app on the local network after upgrading to iOS 14, the new LNA interstitial will appear, followed by the iOS Local Network Access permissions dialog.` It doesn't say anything about custom cast dialogues so I just wanted to clarify that this expected behavior and not a bug in the implementation. Or even if it is expected is there a way to request default scanning behavior be supported with a custom dialog.